# How to create a working Docker Container With .NET 6.0?

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile

I've already managed to create a working container using Node and React.
I'm now trying to create a docker container to operate a simple C# executable which will listen on port 8000 and send back "hello world". It works if I run it locally by visiting http://localhost:8000/
Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:8000/";
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(url);
        listener.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Listening on {0}", url);

        while (true)
        {
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", request.HttpMethod, request.Url);

            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, World!");
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            response.OutputStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I have the built the program and moved it in a folder in the desktop:
[image: This is the folder with the path]

As you can see I've created the Dockerfile, with this content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0      

WORKDIR /HelloWorld

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/HelloWorld/DockerTest.exe"]
```

I've then built the image using:

```
docker build -t imagename:tagname .
```

And then run the container by using:

```
docker run --name containername -p 8000:8000 imagename:tagname
```

The container exits immediately with exit code 1, so a error, and it produces no logs.
What i think I could be doing wrong is using the wrong image for the .NET runtime
(is mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 correct?) or forgetting something else in the Dockerfile. If you have any questions I'll be happy to give you more details

Comment: Is the image on Linux (if i remenber rigth it is)
on the cmd use dotnet HelloWorld.dll

Comment: The Docker file simply copies a folder's contents into the image, it doesn't build your project. What you ask is what the Web API project template produces if you include Docker support. The code itself is 4 lines in .NET 6 using Minimal APIs. Try creating a Minimal API project either in Visual Studio or the command-line and set the `Docker Support` option.

Comment: Yes docker is using Ubuntu even if I'm on Windows. Do you mean DockerTest.dll? Ok I'll try. It should be before, after or in place of "/HelloWorld/DockerTest.exe"?

Comment: Panagiotis the project is already built and working. If I start the file locally I can get hello world from the browser with no problem. Is containerizing it which is causing me trouble

Comment: You have to actually build the project in the Docker file itself and then copy the output to the target image. Both VS and VS Code will add Dockerfiles that do this through a command. Check for example the [ASP.NET Core in a Container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/quickstart-aspnet-core) quickstart. The Dockerfile shown there first compiles the project in an SDK-based image then copies the output to a Runtime-based image

Comment: `is already built and working` not really. Unless you try to execute the file *inside* the `bin\Release\net6.0\publish` folder, you're copying the source code into the image, not the binaries. Try following the tutorials first before customizing them, to see how things actually work

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos OP stated that the files were manually copied from build output folder to the root one (though it is dubious solution but it should work with correct image/command used).

Comment: Panagiotis it is built. I've moved the files from bin\Release\net6.0\publish to a folder in the desktop

Comment: If you build on Windows, you get Windows binaries anyway, which can't run in a Linux container. That's why you *have* to build the application in the Dockerfile. In .NET 7 [publishing directly to Docker images](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updates-to-container-support-in-the-dotnet-sdk/) was added, which means you can get rid of the Dockerfile and create the Docker image through `dotnet publish`. This is shown in the [Publish as a Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container) tutorial

Comment: @GuruStron unless the OP explicitly published for Linux, the binaries would be wrong. There are a *lot* of missing manual steps here, a lot of things that could have gone wrong.

Comment: Yep I agree Panagiotis. I'm new to the thing and I was trying to translate what I just learned using it for node (learned following a tutorial).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0` is a Linux container based on Debian 11 - check out info at [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-runtime/):

> 6.0.16-bullseye-slim-amd64, 6.0-bullseye-slim-amd64, 6.0.16-bullseye-slim, 6.0-bullseye-slim, 6.0.16, **6.0** Dockerfile  **Debian 11**   05/03/2023

So it can't run `.exe` files which are build for Windows.

You need to either switch to Windows container or change command to a valid one for Debian, something like:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

Also you can try using VS tools to [add Docker support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-7.0#existing-app). This should create a [multistage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/) Docker file which will handle both building and producing the resulting image.

P.S.

- Also I would recommend creating an ASP.NET Core project (using [Minimal APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) for simplicity for example) instead of `HttpListener` directly.
- `localhost` in `"http://localhost:8000/"` will mean that it will accept only requests from localhost which in case of dockerized application will be the container itself - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75962189/2501279) for details and solutions.

Comment: Thanks Guru. Can you explain me a couple things?
ENTRYPOINT should be put in place of CMD in the Dockerfile?

Supposing I prefer to switch on a Windows container, where and how can I find one easily? I've got that container through this page: https://mcr.microsoft.com/product/dotnet/runtime/about 
Which is the official one as far as I know. Trying to search words like Net6 and such on Docker Hub only gave me unofficial sources. 

Thanks!

Comment: @David why don't you start from the tutorials and Quickstarts, that explain all this? I posted links to the documentation in the comments that actually show the correct Dockerfiles. Even how you can reduce all this to a single `dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 /t:PublishContainer -c Release` in .NET 7

Comment: @David yes, it should be used instead of `CMD`, check out the link about adding Docker support. Have neve used Windows docker images TBH, the one listed at the docker hub are `Nano Server` and `Windows Server Core`, you can try one of those ([some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-containers/container-base-images#windows-server-core-vs-nanoserver)).

Comment: I shall do that Panagiotis. Thank you. I was just using the opportunity to ask to a real person which could have maybe added something more to it based on his experience

Comment: @David just create the ASP.NET Core app with enabled Docker support. It should handle most problems for you.

Comment: @GuruStron Thanks but how am I supposed to find those images if the search bar nets me lots of unrelated stuff? is there some kind of page on DockerHub which lists them? Sorry if the question is stupid

Comment: @David they are listed at the page which is the first link in my answer.

Comment: @GuruStron What I meant is how do I find something else without asking you every time :) Like how do I get to Explore->.NET Runtime from Explore. If I digit .NET Runtime in the search bar a lot of stuff like consul and mono appears before that

Comment: @David personally I have used google =)

Comment: Oh ok xD
Will do the same! Thanks a lot!
I've tried using ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"] and now it actually starts saying that it listens on port 8000. But when I visit it on localhost i don't receive any answer from it. It's a improvement.

Comment: @David see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75962189/2501279). Localhost will be containers local host.

Comment: Thanks again. After lunch I'm going straight to the tutorial Panagiotis provided. :) It all works now!