# minimal docker for ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, asp.net-core

I can build a simple REST API endpoint with ASP.NET Core:

```bash
$ rm -rf PPP && mkdir PPP && cd PPP # <--- make sure dir is empty
$ dotnet new web 1>/dev/null
$ dotnet run
Building...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5270
# ... omitted other info ...
```

When I send an http `GET` request, everything works fine:

```bash
$ curl http://localhost:5270/
Hello World! # <--- good ! (the default response generate in `dotnet new web`)
```

When I try to "dockerize" it according to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/build-container?tabs=windows&pivots=dotnet-8-0#create-the-dockerfile), it doesn't work:

```bash
# Dockerfile 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0
RUN mkdir Properties
COPY Program.cs Program.cs
COPY PPP.csproj PPP.csproj
COPY appsettings.json appsettings.json
COPY appsettings.Development.json appsettings.Development.json
COPY Properties/launchSettings.json Properties/launchSettings.json
EXPOSE 5270
CMD ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Here is how I build and run the docker image

```
$ docker build --tag host --file Dockerfile .
$ docker run -p 8000:5270 -d -t --name scfrontcs host
```

And here is the error I get:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8000/                 
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

What am I doing wrong ?

---

**EDIT**

- I had trouble running `8.0` on my macos, so I downgraded the image to `7.0`
- I can now send `GET` requests from *within* the docker
- But *not* from outside (from my local machine)

```bash
$ cat Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
WORKDIR /App
COPY Program.cs Program.cs
COPY scfrontcs.csproj scfrontcs.csproj
COPY appsettings.json appsettings.json
EXPOSE 5000
# CMD ["dotnet", "run"] <--- commented, I will run it myself

$ docker build --tag host --file Dockerfile .
$ docker run -p 8000:5000 -d -t --name scfrontcs host
$ docker exec -it scfrontcs bash                     
root@fca567cab821:/App# dotnet run & # inside docker
[1] 97
root@fca567cab821:/App# info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
# ... omitted info ...
curl http://localhost:5000
Hello World # <--- works from within docker !
```

Comment: 8080 and 8081 are the new expose ports in Dockerfile for .NET 8.0. No need to downgrade just use them and they will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`launchSettings.json` [is for development environments only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#lsj):

> The launchSettings.json file:
>
> - Is only used on the local development machine.
> - Is not deployed.
> - Contains profile settings.

And the provided article does not copy it to the docker image.

If as PoC you want to fiddle with it in docker image then you need to set [corresponding environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-8.0#environments) variable (`DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` and/or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` depending on the framework version) to `Development`.

But in general you should not do it, by default ASP.NET Core will listen on `80` (pre .NET 8) or `8080` (.NET 8) port in the container so just use and map to it - `-p 8000:8080`. If you want to use another port inside the container - set [`ASPNETCORE_URLS`](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/) to wanted value or for .NET 8 - `ASPNETCORE_HTTP_PORTS`.

Also add `WORKDIR /App` on the next line after `FROM` - for some reason dotnet command hangs in the root folder (or at least works too long) and wait a bit after starting the container.

But in general it is recommended to follow the standard patterns for image building as one in the docs you have browse. It uses multistage build which allows to reduce the final container size since it will have only runtime without SDK.

See also:

- [Default ASP.NET Core port changed from 80 to 8080](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/containers/8.0/aspnet-port)
- [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments)

Comment: if I understand correctly, I should only copy the following files: `Program.cs`, `*.csproj` and `appsettings.json` ? after that I write `EXPOSE 8080`, but it still doesn't work - should I EDIT my question to reflect what I tried ? Thanks !

Comment: @OrenIshShalom `EXPOSE` is not needed - [`The `EXPOSE` instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published.`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

Comment: @OrenIshShalom have you checked the container logs? Also your docker file look completely different from one in the article.

Comment: I tried to make my docker minimal, so I removed (what I thought was) irrelevant commands. I also tried to be explicit, and `COPY` only what is needed (and therefore the change from `COPY . .` in the docs. Maybe I should have used `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0` instead of `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0` ?

Comment: @OrenIshShalom no, `aspnet:8.0` is runtime image it requires a build app.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom - see the update, you need to add `WORKDIR /App` (or any other folder name)

Comment: Now sending GET requests work from within the docker ! but still, when I send from my local machine it still doesn't work. I'll add the exact description to the question.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom have you fixed the prot mapping as I wrote in the answer? Your fixed docker file with `docker run -p 8000:8080 ...` works just fine for me.

Comment: Could it be something related to my local host machine (macos) ? I edited the exact invocation with the `7.0` version after noticing `8.0` failed executing `dotnet run`.

Comment: @OrenIshShalom can't tell here. Do not have MacOS available.

Comment: (Finally) nailed it. It turns out that setting `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:5000` is mandatory. I somehow thought it was optional. Now everything works ! Thanks a lot Guru Stron !

Comment: @OrenIshShalom the app was listening on `http://localhost:5000` and inside the container localhost is container itself - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/75962189/2501279